# 2020 Mac Mini Ethernet port issue

Tags: network, wifi, mac-mini, ethernet

I just bought a 2020 Mac Mini with 10 gigabit ethernet. I plugged in a cat6 cable into the mac mini's ethernet port and connected it to the wireless router, but it won't connect to the internet, saying that it has self-assigned the IP address. If I use the wifi, however, everything works as expected.

Here are the things I've tried that did not fix the problem.

1. I re-booted the mac mini as well as the router a number of times, which did not do anything.
2. I can also confirm that all ports on the router and the cables (cat6 cable on asus dual band gigabit router) I tried are not faulty as they all worked on my other laptop and desktop (windows and ubuntu).
3. I factory-reset the router and also did a fresh install of OS on the mac mini, which didn't solve the problem at all.
4. As recommended by a few online articles on this issue, I also deleted some of those `.plst` files in the preferences directory and re-booted the mac mini, but this didn't do anything too.
5. I did try hitting `Renew DHCP Lease` button a number of times, and reset the network configurations, followed by a few re-booting. This did not resolve the issue at all. (Note that when I got a new macbook pro a few years ago, I had the same issue, and `Renew DHCP Lease` is what fixed the issue)
6. After hours of googling around, I realized that this issue is potentially caused by the router's DHCP server not giving the mac mini a correct IP. So I changed DHCP settings in the router so that the router will assign a static IP address to the mac mini's MAC address. This also did not do anything.
7. To see if the mac mini's NIC is even functioning. I connected the mac mini directly to the modem using cat6 cable, and the internet worked this way, but I am not sure if I can rule out the mac mini's hardware being faulty based on this evidence.
8. On one occasion when I factory-reset the router, the mac mini was successfully given an IP from the router, and everything worked briefly until I configured WPA2 password. After the password was configured, it stopped working and went back to saying it has self-assigned the IP. And now I am not even able to reproduce this at all.
9. On another occasion when I factory-reset the router, the mac mini was given an IP of `192.168.1.12`. However, the ethernet connection kept dropping, was very unstable, and while the connection was there, the internet was still not working. I tried to assign a static IP to the mac mini, but its IP address remained the same (`192.168.1.12`).
10. Disabling firewall on my router did not fix the problem too.
11. I also checked to see if there's any settings that block devices with certain MAC address from being given IP, but I could not find such settings in the router.

One last thing I did that actually fixed the problem was that I configured the mac's ethernet network settings manually by entering IP address, subnet mask, router, and dns server. And it finally worked. I first put `192.168.1.1` as DNS server, but the internet was still not there. I then entered google's public DNS address, which is `8.8.8.8`. This made everything work.

I have literally tried every solution that I could find online regarding solving this issue, and  the only one that worked was the manual configuration of the ethernet network settings.

I am literally clueless as to why this is happening.

Is the mac mini's network hardware broken? (It works with manual network configurations, and it even worked when directly connected to the modem)

Is my wireless router's hardware broken? (Note, all other devices in my network are working just fine whether wired or wireless)

Is my wireless router (Asus RT-N65U) not compatible with 10gb ethernet in the mac mini? (If so, what router should I get?)

If anyone can give me more information as to what exactly is going on that's causing this issue, I'd be grateful as this has been bugging for me the past few days.

Comment: This is no longer an Apple question as you’ve isolated the problem to your router.  It can obviously connect to the Internet if you statically configure things and will obtain a DHCP lease (step 9).   There’s nothing wrong with the DHCP client software on your  Mac; if there was WiFi wouldn’t work either.  Some advice...in the future, do these steps backward.  Reinstalling and resetting is the *last* thing you want to do, not the first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s no longer about Apple hardware per the OPs own diagnostic steps